# X+Y distibution(proof solution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $X$,$Y$ i.i.d with $f=p(1-p)^n$, $n=0,1,\dots, 0<p<1$.
I am to find PMF of $X+Y=Z$ und its expected value.
It's discrete then
$$P(X=n)=\sum p(1-p)^n$$
$$P(Y=m)=\sum p(1-p)^m$$

and $$P(X+Y) = \sum p(1-p)^n*p(1-p)^{(z-n)} 
= p^2\sum (1-p)^z=p^2 *\frac{1}{(1-(1-p))}=p.$$
Where is the mistake? It looks so simple, but I really don't understand what I did wrong.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

Since $X, Y \geq 0$, the summation should run over $k = 0,1,2, \dots, n$.  Using this your convolution becomes

\begin{eqnarray*} P(X+Y = n) &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} p^2(1-p)^{n} \\
& = & p^2(1-p)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} 1 \\
& = & p^2(1-p)^{n}(n+1) .
& = & (n+1)p^2(1-p)^n
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

**First:** What do you think you are you trying to sum over when you say $\mathsf P(X=n)=\sum p(q-p)^n$ ?

By definition of pmf: $\mathsf P(X=n)=f(n)$ so there is no summation:- $$\mathsf P(X=n)= p(1-p)^n\\\mathsf P(Y=m)=p(1-p)^m$$

**Second:** For the convolution you are summing over all values for $X$ which make $Y=z-X$. Thus the bound term is not $z$, it is $n$ :-

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Y=z) &=\sum_{n=0}^z\mathsf P(X=n, Y=z-n)\\[1ex] &=\sum_{n=0}^z\mathsf P(X=n)\mathsf P(Y=z-n)\\[1ex] &=\sum_{n=0}^z p(1-p)^n\cdot p(1-p)^{z-n}\\[1ex] &= p^2(1-p)^z\cdot\sum_{n=0}^z1 &&\textbf{not }p^2\sum_{z=0}^\infty (1-p)^z \\[1ex] &=(z+1) p^2(1-p)^z\end{align}$$

**TL/DR**:

> Where is the mistake? It looks so simple, but I really don't understand what I did wrong.

You were not clear on what variable you were summing over, nor the bounds.  Since you couldn't say what you should do, you didn't do what you should do.